# Best way to store icon images in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources, icons, project

I want to store in a `VB.NET` project a collection of icon images that I will use on buttons.

What is the best way to store such images in a `VB.NET` project?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
form.button1.Picture = global_icons(14)
form.button2.Picture = global_icons(29)
```

What is the best way to achieve this in `VB.NET`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to manage resource files in your project is to selecting the `Resources` tab in the project properties. You can bring this up by double-clicking My Project in Solution Explorer or your project Properties under the Project menu item.

The resource types that are supported in the Resource Editor are Strings, Images (PNG, BMP, GIF, JPEG, and TIFF are supported!), Icons, Audio Files and so on.

You can add icons by either choosing `Add Existing File`... from the `Add Resources` drop down menu.

Once done you can reference them this way

```
form.button1.Picture = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Icon14")
form.button2.Picture = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Icon29")
```

Comment: Can't you just do: `My.Resources.Icon14` ?

Comment: Yep. That's the shortest way.